# cannot import google.api.client etc

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

First, I'm trying to follow this 'https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java'.

But when copy this example, I cannot run it. ;(

[image]

and my pom.xml file..

```
<!-- google-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev553-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- google-->
```

How can I follow that example?
I want to use google sheets..

env) spring-boot, java8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebuilding the project? Sometimes this helps. Another option you could try is to change the versions.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
    <version>v4-rev516-1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Of course, I tried rebuilding the project several times and asked here. Also, I already changed the version. ;(

Comment: Apologies, I'm way too inexperienced to offer more in-depth solutions. I created a new maven project and simply added these dependencies and had no issue. It might be something that's blocking the dependencies or causing confusion.

Comment: It's OK. finally, I tried a new gradle project. And I successed. Because gradle project depedences from maven repository center.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways.
Finally, I made a new gradle project and I succeed importing that.
Because gradle project uses maven central repository.
So I compared gradle project and maven project dependencies.
And I wrote it on maven pom.xml file.

here is my pom.xml

```
<!-- google-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-sheets -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev516-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jetty/org.mortbay.jetty -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jetty/org.mortbay.jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5-20081211</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks.